# Get variable by name inside function that will be imorted Python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, global

I try to track changes of the `dataframe` to create a report at the end of `Jupiter` notebook so I use `magic` for it. I get some dataframe's name as a string and need to get the value of it. I used globals()['df'] and everything was fine until I moved `magics_class` into a separate file so that when imported it uses another `globals()`.

Are there any mechanisms to make imported module use globals from where it was imported or any other ways to get values of a variable by name?

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
def print_df_by_name(name='df'):
    print(globals()[name])
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2]})
print_df_by_name('df')
```

Everything is ok, now create file my_module.py with such content:

```
def print_df_by_name(name='df'):
    print(globals()[name])

def show_module_globals_keys():
    print(globals().keys())
```

If we try to import our module the function won't work:

```
from my_module import *

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2]})

print_df_by_name('df')
```

This will raise an error, because it uses globals of the file, it can be seen with second function we created:

```
show_module_globals_keys()
```

Comment: It would be nice if you included a small relevant example of the code in the imported module that references the variable. It might be as simple as `imported_module.df`.

Comment: "I get some dataframe's name as a string and need to get the value of it" - why the string?

Comment: Magics in jupyter return following cell as a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass the calling module's `__name__` to the print function and use that to get the `DataFrame`.

## my_module.py

```
import sys

def print_df_by_name(name='df', module_name=None):
    print(getattr(sys.modules[module_name], name))
```

## calling_script.py

```
import pandas as pd

from my_module import *

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2]})

print_df_by_name(name='df', module_name=__name__)
```

## output

```
§ python calling_script.py
   A
0  1
1  2
```